# How to run rake tasks with warbler with -cp option

Tags: ruby, rake, jruby, war, warbler

I have a jruby app that is being packaged into a war file. I am trying to run a rake task from my app. I know warbler gives a -S option to run rake tasks.

When I run the following command, everything runs fine:

```
java -jar /path/to/war/file/app.war -S rake namespace:start_task
```

But when I try to run the same command with a -cp option as follows. I get an error.

```
java -cp /path/to/war/file/app.war -S rake namespace:start_task
```

Error:

```
Unrecognized option: -S
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I am using a gem that has hard coded the -cp option to invoke execute the war file. I am wondering if there is a way to invoke a rake task in warbler using the -cp option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`java -jar` does look for the main-class in the specified archive

`java -cp` does only add a .jar to class-path

... it doesn't know what main-class to run you will need to set it manually

e.g. `java -cp app.war WarMain -S ...`